# kill process by batchfile (remote)

Tags: vb.net, deployment, batch-file, remote-debugging, remote-access

I have developed a application that is running on computer A. I have a computer B with a running version of visual studio (where I designed the application).

What I got is, when I built my application on computer B, it deploys it to computer A (by a shared network folder.

now, the thing I want now is using the `pre-built` and `post-built` commands in visual studio to call a batchfile. The pre-built command batchfile needs to kill the application (if it is running) on the remote computer (computer A) i think this can be dont by processid, or processname. The post-built command batch file needs to start the "fresly" built app on the remote computer. but I dont't really know where to start,

How do i accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb896649).

[PsKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb896683) and [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb897553), respectively, are the tools you are looking for.

Here is a [similar question about starting remote processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711604/starting-remote-processes-in-a-windows-network)

Comment: Where can i set the name of my application's process. Or what is that name by default?

Comment: The process (image) name is the own executable filename.