# Remote execute Windows process in the context of another machine

Tags: windows, cpu, distributed, execution, remote-server

Is it possible to execute a non interactive Windows process on remote machine B, but in the context of a different machine A (in my case the one giving the execute order).

What I try to achieve, is to use the CPU/power of a remote machine to run an executable, but it needs to use automatically the resources of my machine. That is, if the executable references a file (e.g. c:\dir\myfile.txt) or registry, it will automatically use "my" "c:\dir\myfile.txt" disk and registry and not the machine on which is actually executed.

Thanks

Comment: How possible is this?

Comment: No.  Windows does not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ca achieve that with some type of Client /Server protocol. Host B listens to requests and saves the requests host Information. After that Host A gets a server state and listens to file/directory requests from host B. While the first connection is still alive it can be finished with the application result and a finished Handshake or something similar.

Comment: If i have to implement it yes, probably. What I ask is there an existing way to do it.

Comment: What exactly do you want? a library? I explained an existing way; you only have to implement that algorithm. But maybe boost asio is what you are searching for. (or every else networking library).
also look at that: [starting remote processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711604/starting-remote-processes-in-a-windows-network?rq=1)

Comment: I want to use remote compilation with compiler that is not made for it. That is, I want the compiler to use my machine registry, disk, .dlls, everything except CPU and Memory which must be used remotely